# accessing report check box in module (ms access)

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to write a module to the database but i need to access checkboxs value from a report form. How do i access the form contents in a module? (I am using access 2007)

Here is the code which is in onclick event of the report which contains check boxes but i need to run a macro which does different thing in the same onclick event too so i was hoping to call a module using runcode in that macro.

```
    Private Sub Command9_Click()
       Dim query As String
       Dim qdfNew As QueryDef
       Dim dbLib As Database
       Set dbLib = CurrentDb()




        If Me.ReferenceCheck.Value = True Then
           query1 = " Record_Num, [Report_Num], [Title], [Report_Date], [Author], [Organization], [Test Org], [Test Name], [Test Date], [POC]"


        Else
           query1 = ""
        End If

       If Me.SoilCheck.Value = True Then
           query2 = "[Soil Condition],[Soil_C_Method], [Soil Compaction Method],[Custom Soil Compaction Method], [General Soil Classification], [Water Content Expedient], [Dry Density Expedient], [LL]"


        Else
           query2 = ""

       End If

   queryHead = "SELECT "
   queryTail = " FROM searchR"

   finalQuery = queryHead
   If Me.ReferenceCheck.Value = True Then
      finalQuery = finalQuery & query1

   End If

   If Me.SoilCheck.Value = True Then
      If finalQuery = "SELECT " Then
          finalQuery = finalQuery & query2
      Else
          finalQuery = finalQuery & ", " & query2

      End If

   End If    

       If (finalQuery = "SELECT ") Then
             finalQuery = "SELECT * FROM searchR"
       Else
             finalQuery = finalQuery & queryTail
       End If


       dbLib.QueryDefs.Delete "filterQuery"
       Set qdfNew = dbLib.CreateQueryDef("filterQuery", finalQuery)
       Child0.Form.RecordSource = "filterQuery"


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could run the macro from in your code

```
DoCmd.RunMacro "myMacro"
```

and I am wondering why you are going to the trouble of deleting and creating a query def. In the first instance you could just modify the one that is there but even more simply just assign the SQL as the record source.

```
Child0.Form.Recordsource = finalQuery
```